# Получение содержимого или iframe в iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Не могу получить содержимое div который находится в большом кол-ве iframe. 
Пример:

```
<iframe>
<iframe> <div id="1"></div></iframe>
</iframe>

<iframe>
</iframe>
```

Могу сразу предупредить id у iframe нет точнее есть но он постоянно меняется и значит что он не уникален. Получить див просто по айди не удастся так для начала нужно получить доступ к фрэйму в котором он находится.
Пробовал так:

```
 var ifrs=window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    var fr;
    for(var i=0; i < ifrs.length; i++ )

    {

var ifrsi=ifrs[i];

var DOC = ifrsi.contentDocument;
var result = DOC.getElementById("1");


    }
```

Получилось найти только двай фрейма основных, но не нашло фрэймы которые есть внутри этих фреймах так как опять же нужно получить доступ к фрэймам.

Так и не могу понять как добраться до этого div.

Получилось добраться до нужного ФРЕЙМА, но получает его в виде объекта:

```
window.frames['ext-gen-top66'].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
```

вид происходящего

```
[iframe#ext-comp-785523, iframe#detail-ext-gen-listdetail-0-23-458611.ux-mif, ext-comp-785523: iframe#ext-comp-785523, list-ext-gen-listdetail-0-22-154430: iframe#ext-comp-785523, detail-ext-gen-listdetail-0-23-458611: iframe#detail-ext-gen-listdetail-0-23-458611.ux-mif]
```

Comment: Разве `iframe` ещё кто-то пользуется? Фрейм во фрейме, что происходит?

Comment: Вот я сам в шоке. Но к сожалению мне не дают трогать html.

Comment: Я так понял, что у iframe есть src с разных документов и всего их три? Первый iframe ссылается на второй iframe, а второй на div?

Comment: Да. Только как получить содержимое не имея id фрейма